# Regarding self complementary trees if such exist.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Can anybody please tell me whether there are any self complementary trees and if so, how many and what are the conditions and the properties it holds? Thank You.

Comment: Apart from the 1-vertex graph, the only other one is $4$-vertex path.

Comment: Ohhh thanx a lot!!!! :)